# how to allow using make_shared in android ndk

Tags: c++, android-ndk

Finally I was able to use **shared_ptr** in Elcipse/NDK by adding:

`#include <tr1/shared_ptr.h>`

But I can't find the way to also use **make_shared**

Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: As I recall, it was only added in actual C++11. Boost has a `shared_ptr` and `make_shared`, however, not to mention the generally more favourable `unique_ptr` and it seems a `make_unique` is in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **make_shared**, you need to choose one of these **APP_STL** in **Application.mk**:

```
gnustl_static   -> Use the GNU STL as a static library.
gnustl_shared   -> Use the GNU STL as a shared library.
c++_static      -> Use the LLVM libc++ as a static library.
c++_shared      -> Use the LLVM libc++ as a shared library.
```

See NDK [CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT doc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/text/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.text) for more details.